# Mercator projection with metric grid overlay (metre increments from centre) - GMT Generic Mapping Tools

Tags: unix, grid, overlay, gmt, mercator

I have a plot of Montserrat, centred on -62.2°,16.75°, with a Mercator projection created using Generic Mapping Tools (GMT), as below.

[image]

I would like to add a grid on top of this, using the centre as the origin. However, I would like to produce the overlying grid in terms of metres, rather than degrees.
Is there a way in which I can assign -62.2°,16.75° as the origin, and then produce grid lines of multiples of 1000m from the origin (1000m, 2000m, 5000m, etc) (perhaps through psxy?)?

The code used to produce this plot is

```
set loc_area = -R-63.2/-61.2/15.75/17.75
set loc_proj = -Jm3.25i
set outfile = bath_map.ps

psbasemap $loc_area $loc_proj -O -Bf1a1WSen:.'Montserrat Local': -X7.5i -Y0 -K >> $outfile
grdimage $loc_area $loc_proj -O -Clant.cpt lant_topo.nc -K >> $outfile
grdcontour lant_topo.nc -Ccont.cpt -A- -Q100 -W $loc_area $loc_proj -O -K >> $outfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the degrees into meters; your grid will be super small

```
gmt pscoast -R-62.25/-62.12/16.65/16.84 -JM6i -P -B.01666666g.00898311174 -Ggray -Dh -Slightblue -Wred > GMT_tut_4.ps
```

[image]

Comment: What about if he wishes to go further and dispense with the lat/lon around the edges, instead showing meter numbers?